# Selenium Best Practice: One Long Test or Several Successively Long Tests?

Tags: selenium

In Selenium I often find myself making tests like ...

```
// Test #1
login();

// Test #2
login();
goToPageFoo();

// Test #3
login();
goToPageFoo();
doSomethingOnPageFoo();

// ...
```

In a unit testing environment, you'd want separate tests for each piece (ie. one for `login`, one for `goToPageFoo`, etc.) so that when a test fails you know exactly what went wrong.  However, I'm not sure this is a good practice in Selenium.

It seems to result in a lot of redundant tests, and the "know what went wrong" problem doesn't seem so bad since it's usually clear what went wrong by looking at the what step the test was on.  And it certainly takes longer to run a bunch of "build up" tests than it takes to run just the last ("built up") test.

Am I missing anything, or should I just have a single long test and skip all the shorter ones building up to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a large test suite in Selenium using a lot of smaller tests (like in your code example). I did it for exactly the same reasons you did. To know "what went wrong" on a test failure.

This is a common best practice for standard unit tests, but if I had to do it over again, I would go mostly with the second approach. Larger built-up tests with some smaller tests when needed.

The reason is that Selenium tests take an order of magnitude longer than standard unit tests to run, particularly on longer scenarios. This makes the whole test suite unbearably long with most of the time being spent on running the same redundant code over and over again.

When you do get an error, say in a step that is repeated at the beginning of 20+ different tests, it does not really help to know you got the same error 20+ times. My test runner runs my test out of order so my first error isn't even on the first incremental test of the "build-up" series so I end up looking at the first test failure and it's error message to see where the failure came from. The same thing I would do with if I had used larger "built-up" tests.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I knew I couldn't get a canonical answer for such a subjective question, but even your (subjective) answer, as someone with experience, really helps me feel like I'm not about create a giant mess by using longer tests.